# For читает только последний элемент

Tags: javascript, three.js

Имеется цикл, который прогоняет возможные варианты столкновения двух или более объектов с массивом BB_array. Всё бы хорошо, но только когда цикл запускается, он читает только последний элемент массива "BB_move_brush_array".

P.s. console.log('bruh!') выводится при столкновении всех элементов BB_move_brush_array с массивом BB_array, но visible false/true позволяет делать только с последним BB_move_brush_array

```js
function init(){
    brush1 = new Brush( new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 5, 5, 0.0001 ), material );
    brush1_oper = new Operation( new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 5, 5, 0.0001 ), material );
    
    wall_mesh_array.push(brush1);
    scene.add(wall_mesh_array[0]);
    wall_mesh_array[0].position.x = 0;
    
    brush1BB = new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3());
    brush1BB.setFromObject(brush1);
    BB_array.push(brush1BB);
    
    brush2 = new Brush( new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 5, 5, 0.0001 ), material );
    brush2_oper = new Operation( new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 5, 5, 0.0001 ), material );
    
    wall_mesh_array.push(brush2);
    scene.add(wall_mesh_array[1]);
    wall_mesh_array[1].position.x = 6;
    
    brush2BB = new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3());
    brush2BB.setFromObject(brush2);
    BB_array.push(brush2BB);
    
    brush3 = new Brush( new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 5, 5, 0.0001 ), material );
    brush3_oper = new Operation( new THREE.BoxBufferGeometry( 5, 5, 0.0001 ), material );
    
    wall_mesh_array.push(brush3);
    scene.add(wall_mesh_array[2]);
    wall_mesh_array[2].position.x = 12;
    
    brush3BB = new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3());
    brush3BB.setFromObject(brush3);
    BB_array.push(brush3BB);
    
    brush4 = new Brush( new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 5), material_test );
    
    brush4_oper = new Operation(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 5), material_test);
    brush4_oper.operation = SUBTRACTION;
    brush4_oper.position.x = 0;
    oper_move_mesh_array.push(brush4_oper);
    
    move_mesh_array.push(brush4);
    scene.add(move_mesh_array[0]);
    move_mesh_array[0].position.x = 0;
    move_mesh_array[0].position.z = 5;
    move_mesh_array[0].isDraggable = true;
    
    brush4BB = new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3());
    brush4BB.setFromObject(brush4);
    BB_move_brush_array.push(brush4BB);
    
    brush5 = new Brush( new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 5), material_test );
    
    brush5_oper = new Operation(new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 5), material_test);
    brush5_oper.operation = SUBTRACTION;
    brush5_oper.position.x = 0;
    oper_move_mesh_array.push(brush5_oper);
    
    move_mesh_array.push(brush5);
    scene.add(move_mesh_array[1]);
    move_mesh_array[1].position.x = 6;
    move_mesh_array[1].position.z = 5;
    move_mesh_array[1].isDraggable = true;
    
    brush5BB = new THREE.Box3(new THREE.Vector3(), new THREE.Vector3());
    brush5BB.setFromObject(brush5);
    BB_move_brush_array.push(brush5BB);
}
    
    function updateCSG() {
        for(let i = 0; i < BB_move_brush_array.length; i++){
            for(let j = 0; j < BB_array.length; j++){
                if(BB_move_brush_array[i].intersectsBox(BB_array[j])){
                    wall_mesh_array[j].visible = false;
                    console.log('bruh!')
                }else{
                    wall_mesh_array[j].visible = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    function animate() {
        requestAnimationFrame(animate);
    
        updateCSG();
    }
```

Comment: откуда известно, что только последний?

Comment: потому что visible false/true происходит только при соприкосновении последнего элемента BB_move_brush_array с массивом BB_array, можно кнч использовать фиксированный Index массива, тогда всё будет работать, но по отдельности, а надо чтоб работало соприкосновение всех элементов массива

Comment: Для понимания проблемы нужно еще примеры тех массивов увидеть... Т.е. полностью рабочий вариант программы нужно показывать. ;)

Comment: @Kromster, расскажи что именно ты заредактировал в этом сообщении? Так, для моего правильного понимания... :) Ведь код ТСа запустить все рано не получится...

Comment: @Эникейщик, это как раз правильное редактирование? Мне интересно это понять...

Comment: @ksa вопросу было 10минут от роду, я убрал бесполезное приветствие. Можем обсудить в чате

Comment: @ksa добавил код с массивами

Comment: @ksa код выглядит безобразно, шарю, я его потом редачить буду, сейчас надо шоб просто работало

Comment: @ksa Да, это нормальное редактирование. Убрано ненужное приветствие из свежего вопроса. А делить на абзацы вопросы, или править пунктуацию и прочие мелочи в вопросах, которым уже несколько лет - излишне.

Comment: "потому что visible false/true происходит только при соприкосновении последнего элемента " - откуда это известно? Вы изменяете одини и те же переменные несколько раз. Код выполняется за микросекунды, вы успеваете за микросекунды увидеть изменение значений? Вы видите только результат после последней итерации. Если у вас после первого элемента стало true, а после последнего false, то именно false вы и увидите.

Comment: @Эникейщик окей, с этим понятно, как тогда сделать - так, чтобы эта дичь работала?

Comment: для начала нужно определиться с тем, а что собственно должно получиться в результате работы этой дичи

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/143108/discussion-between-leonerdo-and-).

Comment: Например все эти `false/true` собрать в массив. Так хоть увидишь что у тебя получилось и потом с этим можно что-то дальше делать.